# Getting 404 error when using the Google API with PHP to get calendar events

Tags: php, api, calendar

I get this error in PHP when trying to access a Google Calendar via API:

Message: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/CALENDARID/events?maxResults=10&orderBy=startTime&singleEvents=true&timeMin=2019-12-25T00%3A00%3A00-05%3A00&timeMax=2019-12-25T23%3A59%3A59-05%3A00&timeZone=America%2FNew_York&key=KEY: (404) Not Found

PHP:

```php
require APPPATH . "third_party/google-api-php/src/Google/autoload.php";
$this->client = new Google_Client();
$this->client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar Api');
$this->client->setAuthConfigFile('<PATH TO JSON FILE>');
$this->client->setDeveloperKey('<DEVELOPERKEY>');
$this->client->setAccessType('offline');
$this->client->setApprovalPrompt('consent');
$this->client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$this->client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
```

PHP:

```php
$results = $this->googlecalendar_model->calendar->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
```

Any idea on the cause of the 404 error?

Comment: Did you already change `CALENDARID` in the URL? maybe the `CALENDARID` is not found

Comment: yes I set the CALENDARID to the ID I want to display